# npm install local-package creates symbolik link

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have a local npm package that I install into my nodjes project with `npm install path-to-local-package`. The problem is that when I run `npm install` the module is installed in my node_modules as a symbolic link which causes problems when I need to copy over the code to the target device that I'm supposed to run the code on.

Is there a way to make npm install to copy the local module into the using projects node_modules folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of `npm 5.3.0`, this is not possible.

> npm install <folder>:
>
> Install the package in the directory as a symlink in the current
>   project. Its dependencies will be installed before it's linked. If
>    sits inside the root of your project, its dependencies may be
>   hoisted to the toplevel node_modules as they would for other types of
>   dependencies.

You could try hosting a local npm registry using something like [Sinopia](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinopia), but depending on the scope of your issue that may be more trouble than its worth.